# Pie Chart to represent aggregate values - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts, ngx-charts

What is the recommended type of chart to use to show aggregate value? I'm guessing bar chart is the best but can I use a doughnut chart?
For example, I want to show that 30 people have visited my website today. Can I represent this in a pie chart or doughnut chart? I'm planning to use `ngx-charts` or `ng2-charts` for my Angular 5 application.

Comment: your statements are contradicting "I want to show that 30 people have visited my website today"  and then "doughnut chart without knowing the total value? "

Comment: ok after the edit, do you have any other info?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Can I represent in a doughnut chart the summation of number of people each day without having a designated target value? So today I show 30, tomorrow 10 people visit, so i show 40.